# How does the operator >+ differ from >= in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Entirely by accident today I was running a SQL statement to filter some items by date, for simplicity sake we'll say I used

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TableName] 
WHERE [RecordCreated] >+ '2016-04-10'
```

Only after the statement ran I realised I had used >+ instead of >=, now I was confused as I would have expected an error.

I tried a couple of other variations such as

```
>- -- Throws an error
<+ -- Ran successfully
<- -- Throws an error
```

The count of rows returned was exactly the same whether I used >= or >+

After searching online I couldn't find any documentation that covered this syntax directly, only when the two operators are used apart.

The `RecordCreated` column is a `datetime`.

Is this just a nicety in syntax for a possible common mistake or is it potentially trying to cast the date as a numeric value?

Comment: Interesting.  I would expect this to parse using `+` as a unary operator (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174362.aspx).  However, I'm surprised it works on a string/date literal.

Comment: It's not an operator. It's two operators next to each other. And you'll get different results if there are any rows with `RecordCreated` exactly equal to `2016-04-10`.

Comment: This is either a bug in the parser or a bug in the documentation. `SELECT +'plus!'` yields `plus!`, even though by all accounts it should not, since unary plus supposedly only works on numeric types and the string concatenation operator requires another expression. (Since the string remains a string, this is not one of the cases where T-SQL's fetish for implicit conversions is the problem.)

Comment: What is the type of your `RecordCreated` field?

Comment: The type is datetime, will update the question to reflect that

Comment: This makes for nice material for an obfuscated T-SQL quiz -- what's the result of `SELECT ++'-1'++'1'++2` and why?

Comment: MSFT: *this behavior is by design since + is an unary operator. So the parser accepts "+ <expression>, and the '+' is simply ignored in this case.* https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/718176/concatenation-operator-not-working-properly

Comment: Interresting... Just tried this on a 250k rows table having _datetime_ `START_DT` column : `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons WHERE START_DT > '2001-01-01'` returns 187.057 rows and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons WHERE START_DT >+ '2001-01-01'` returns exactly the same number. Thus the `>` operator combined with `+` unary operator seems to be the explanation

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: it's more subtle than that -- unary + is a no-op for *any* type. The fact that `DATETIME` can be converted to a number is irrelevant. `+NEWID()` is also perfectly fine, for example. Someone took a shortcut implementing this operator. So `A >+ B` is always the same as `A > B` (provided the expression is syntactically legal in the first place, of course).

Comment: Ahh yes, I see the issue now. The connect from Alex says it all.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with '+' operator.

As per the updates from Microsoft team,

> After some investigation, this behavior is by design since + is an
>   unary operator. So the parser accepts "+ , and the '+' is
>   simply ignored in this case. Changing this behavior has lot of
>   backward compatibility implications so we don't intend to change it &
>   the fix will introduce unnecessary changes for application code.

You can find a really good answer by [RGO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646390/rgo) to his own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13218911/4923740).

Answer (score -2):

The result shouldn't match with ">=" and "<=" but with ">" and "<". Just checked and the rowcound varies by 2 - the first and last item is removed.

Comment: I have just tried your example specifically and the count is the same for >, >+ and >=, I think as @Damien_The_Unbeliever says it may change if there was a record that exactly matched, I am yet to try that test.

Comment: OK, would be interesting to know. I just tried on a "standard" Date Dimension table and filtered by date... and as mentioned, the first and the last date were skipped if I used >+ and <+

Comment: When I passed in a date that would be an exact match '2016-04-11 09:27:51.217' the count differed by 1 between >= and >+, demonstrating that >+ does ignore exact matches. Doesn't look to affect the last row however.

Comment: When I queried with "where datum >+ '2016-01-01' AND datum <+ '2016-01-10'", January 1st and January 10th where removed