# Why does the `+` between 2 columns not produce an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Look at the following simple query

```
select u.UserID,
       u.UserFirst,
       u.UserLast
from   tblUser u
```

This produces 11 rows, with 3 columns, as expected

Now look at this query

```
select u.UserID,
       u.UserFirst,
       +
       u.UserLast
from   tblUser u
```

This produces the exact same result.
Both `UserFirst` and `UserLast` are varchar columns, but since there is a `comma` between the 2 columns, sql server will not concatinate them.

But I expected sql server to return an error with the second query, why is it not producing an error ?

**EDIT**
if I try it with an minus, than i do get an error

```
select u.UserID,
       u.UserFirst,
       -      
       u.UserLast
from   tblUser u
```

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for minus operator.

Comment: I think its the same principle as when you `SELECT +1`. On the left side of the operator there can be an expression, but there doesn't have to be one.

Comment: You are 'signing' the value, for positive values doesn't make any sense, is redundance, but you can not get a negative value of a varchar

Comment: what happens is that you are concatenating an empty value at the beginning (before the +) with the next column. `u.UserLast`

Comment: I think there was an acknowleged bug on the old connect site about allowing unary plus for strings but marked as won't fix

Comment: @DanielBrughera So you are saying that signing an varchar to positive is ignored, but signing it to negavite is not. And therefore the error only appears when adding the minus ?

Comment: @GuidoG, yes, all values have a positive, but not all of them have a negative

Comment: To produce an error  you should have concatenate different data types,  u.UserFirst, and u.UserLast are in same dataType and your  operator + . For the second time you impose minus operator for  char data type . minus operator is work for int not varchar.

Comment: @Esteban is not a concat, is signing

Comment: This isn't about signing, it's about concatenation. You can concatenate varchars with a  `+`. @Esteban is correct.

Comment: See the quote from Microsoft at the end of the answer in the dupe

Comment: Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218892/sql-server-unary-operator-on-non-numeric-strings) on SO

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the dupe, I found lots of info but missed this one